# Style rows based on data in jQuery Datatables

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

Is there a way to style rows based on the data in a jQuery Datatables table? For example, if one row has a cell with value 1, it would have background-color green, while another row has a cell with value 0, that row would have background-color red. The data is populated with json.

Comment: The "duplicate" answer refers to the old, deprecated API for DataTables.

Comment: It led me to the current answer though, a "createdRow" callback: https://datatables.net/examples/advanced_init/row_callback.html , so thank you.